# Custom legend with ggplot2 in R having multiple density plots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a legend to my plot, and here's what I have for now:

```
require(ggplot2)
d1 = data.frame(rnorm(100, mean=5))
d2 = data.frame(rnorm(50, mean=7))
single_data = 5.5
max_y = max(max(density(d1[,1])$y), max(density(d2[,1])$y))
print(ggplot() + geom_density(aes(x=d1), colour='black', data=d1, kernel='gaussian', alpha=.1, fill='red') + 
        geom_density(aes(x=d2), colour="black", data=d2, kernel='gaussian', alpha=.1, fill='blue') + 
        geom_segment(aes(x=single_data, xend=single_data, y=0, yend=max_y), colour='blue') +
        xlab("Count") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle('Main Title') +
        theme(legend.position='right') +
        scale_color_manual(name = "Data",
                           labels = c(5, 7),
                           values = c('red', 'blue'))
)
```

I expect to see a legend on the right side of the plot, but here's the output:

[image: Code sample output]

How can I add a legend for these two density plots?

Comment: Legends are made for things you map to in `aes`, like color, fill, shape... You have none. But other than that, well formed question, example code, picture of the output. It's got it all, Kate Winslet would marry it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code that can come pretty close. You can fiddle with the rest.

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(9)
d1 = data.frame(d1 = rnorm(100, mean=5))
d2 = data.frame(d2 = rnorm(50, mean=7))
single_data = 5.5

xy <- data.frame(d1 = d1, d2 = d2)

library(tidyr)
xy <- gather(xy)

ggplot(xy, aes(x = value, fill = key)) +
  geom_density(kernel = "gaussian", alpha = 0.1) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = single_data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(density=c(rnorm(50, mean=5), rnorm(50, mean=7)),
                 name=c(rep('d1', 50), rep('d2', 50)))

single_data = 5.5
max_y = max(max(density(d1[,1])$y), max(density(d2[,1])$y))

p1 <- ggplot(data=df) +
        geom_density(aes(x=density, group=name, colour=name, fill=name), kernel='gaussian', alpha=.5) + 
        geom_segment(aes(x=single_data, xend=single_data, y=0, yend=max_y), colour='blue') +
  scale_color_manual('Legend Name', labels=c('density 1', 'density 2'), values=c('blue', 'green')) +
  scale_fill_manual('Legend Name', labels=c('density 1', 'density 2'), values=c('blue', 'green')) +
        xlab("Count") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle('Main Title') +
        theme(legend.position='right')
p1
```

You have to build decent dataframes before ploting them. That's the key to the ggplot superiority :p. Here you vertical segment is not included in the legend. If you want it to be so, you have to use the color aesthetic for the segment and the fill aesthetic for the densities (instead of both for the densities as it is in the example).

Comment: Thanks, I'm now trying to do what you mentioned with the segment line, and to change the alpha of the fill color in the legend.
And as a side note, I originally had my two vectors in two variables because I didn't know how to merge vectors of different lengths in one data.frame, which is solved in the other given answer here.